# Batch Paged Requests

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve the news feed for a user, and using the Graph API that returns multiple pages.  I'd like to get four pages, and that's pretty slow, so I'd like to batch a request for all pages into one request using batching.  I can't figure out how to batch-request multiple pages - clearly each request in the batch is dependent on the previous.

I wrote up a webpage to let me test this all out, containing the following form:

```
<form method="GET" action="https://graph.facebook.com">
<input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="blahblahblah">

<input type="hidden" name="batch" value="[{'method':'GET', 'name':'getnews',
   'omit_response_on_success':false, 'relative_url':'me/home'},{'method':'GET', 
   'relative_url':'{result=getnews:$.paging.next}'}]">

<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Of course, when I get a response from Facebook that requires paging, the paging.next value is a full URL and the batching functionality wants a relative_url, so my first request works and my second request returns with the paging.next URL in a "body" key.

I found a piece of facebook documentation which states that a request like the following works, where you graph.facebook.com is followed by a full URL specifying a request://graph.facebook.com/http://graph.facebook.com/me/home?_fb_url=me/home&access_token=blahblahblah"

I was surprised to find that this works, but it does when I just make that GET request to the Graph API.  Unfortunately, the batching functionality does not allow me to put that full URL in the "relative_url" field - it just does that "body" thing.

Does anybody have a good way to batch requests for multiple pages?  kongo09 and I were wondering this over in the facebook dev forum, but I guess that's on its way out...  http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=107098

Thanks,
-Karl

Comment: Could you add a ?limit= parameter to the initial load and retrieve a larger set of data in the first request?

Comment: Lol, well, that works now.  I swear that last time I tried anything greater than limit=25 FB would return an error.  Actually, now that I think about it, when I was testing that Graph API was having some other problems...
Thanks Igy, I'm going to run with that for now.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Have you found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way:

You should use

```
"relative_url":"me/home?after={result=getnews:$.paging.cursors.after}"
```